# Don't run your own ORM Implementation, but

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data

the Topic already says one of the key roles regarding ORM

> Don't run your own ORM Implementation

But, I have a situation here where I'm not sure how to get our Requirements implemented properly.
To give you a bit of background, currently we are using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate as JPA Implementation and all is fine so far.
But we have separate fields which we want to "manage" automatically, a bit similar to Auditing Annotations from Hibernate (`@CreatedBy`, `@ModifiedBy`, ...).
In our case this is e.g. a specific "instance" the entity belongs to.
Our Application is rather a Framework than an App, so other Developers frequently add Entities and we want to keep it simple and intuitive.

But, we do not only want to set it automatically on storage but also add it as condition for most "simple and frequent" queries (see my related question here [Inject further query conditions / inject automatic entity field values when using Spring Data JPA Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283251/inject-further-query-conditions-inject-automatic-entity-field-values-when-usin)).
Thus, I thought about building a simple Layer on top of the `EntityManager` and its Criteria API to support at least simple Queries like

- `findById(xx)`
- `findByStringAttribute(String attribute, String value)`
- `findByIntegerAttribute(int attribute, String value)`
- ...

I'm not sure if this is too broad of a question but, what are your thoughts on that? Is this a reasonable idea or should I skip that idea?

Comment: I find it odd that you would want a "find by string attribute" kind of generic method, which might make sense in a NoSQL repository, but certainly not with a RDBMS. I would use the mechanisms provided by Hibernate/JPA as much as possible (and they have a lot of mechanisms), and avoid any custom layers where you can't be sure that it works nicely with the other parties involved.

Comment: I agree with you @Kayman, this is ugly but the only way to achieve such queries on this high level. It would be nicer for me to be able to inject it somewhere "deeper" (e.g. in the generated CriteriaBuilder from Spring Data JPA but currently this does not seem to be possible, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1551 or https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1646).

Comment: I meant on the JPA level, not the higher Spring abstraction level. There's all kinds of listeners and interceptors that can affect the querying process. I still consider your example repository methods to be misguided. The naming scheme was supposed to make the code readable and queries generatable in a typesafe way, e.g. `findUserByUserName`. You suggest `findById()` which already exists and 2 generic find by attribute methods which really fight against the philosophy of the whole `Repository` functionality.

Comment: @Kayaman I went through the code as I would also like to keep these method names as they currently are. But there currently is no way to inject custom processing of the generated Query in Spring Data JPA. So right now one could not use both, manual query post processing AND Spring Data JPA Repositories, sadly.